# Named route isnt added to Domain || Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

So I set my routes up like this:

I set my initial route:

```
 initialRoute: "/",
```

& then my onGenerateRoutes:

```
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case HomePage.route:
        int? selectedIndex = settings.arguments as int?;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                HomePage(selectedIndex: selectedIndex ?? 0));
      case FPassword.route:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const FPassword(),
        );
    }
  },
```

Im saving the route itself in each corresponding class:

```
static const String route = '/password';
```

& im navigating like:

```
onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                          context, HomePage.route,
                          arguments: 0),
```

But the problem that Im facing is that the route itself isnt appearing in my domain, it always stays like:

> http://localhost:61694/#/

It doesnt change. I already ran pub clean, started everything anew & so on. So where have I made my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Define the routes something like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Named Routes Demo',
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => const FirstScreen(),
    '/second': (context) => const SecondScreen(),
  },
)
```

See [Navigate with named routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) for details.

Paths written without a hash e.g `foo.bar/second`:

```
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(App());
}
```

See [Configuring the URL strategy on the web](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies) for details.

Comment: but how can I define the routes like that when they expect args?

Comment: To access arguments in the target route use ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments.

Comment: so there is no way of achieving my wished behavior with onGenerateRoute?